# Lenovo H50-55 desktop (90BG0024RK) boots to black screen

Tags: windows-7, boot, black-screen-of-death, lenovo-desktop-computer

We have a Lenovo H50-55 desktop (90BG0024RK) equipped with an AMD A8-7600 processor. The system runs Windows 7 Pro x64 and has domain users.

The problem we're experiencing is specific to that Lenovo PC. After booting up, the system displays a black screen, with only a (working) mouse cursor. The problem can only be corrected by shutting it down and restoring it.

Why is this happening, and how might we fix this?

Comment: Try changing sata data cable and power cable. Check your RAM and HDD for errors.

Comment: can you open task manager when it boots up with a black screen ?

Comment: Nope. It is not possible. Only mouse is moving.

Comment: No suggestions? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That topic can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue was solved. I changed windows 7 to windows 10 and works fine without black screen.

I think that Lenovo PC's had suitable problem with windows 7 or with its updates.

Comment: I'm glad you no longer have the problem, but I don't think we can assume that all Lenovo PCs running Windows 7 must be upgraded to Windows 10.

Comment: maybe it was fault of windows 7 images which were provided to us from the company which was making us domain services.